# Firebase functions onCreate user

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create a new doc, collection and another doc with data on onCreate user in firebase functions. Please see code below

```
exports.newUser =  functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

var data = {
        Fabric: 10, 
        Leather: 10,
        Paint: 10,
        Wheel: 10,
        Windscreen: 10  
      };

//Create new doc/collection/doc and set fields from data.
    return admin.firestore()
    .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
      .collection('settings')
      .doc('expiredates')
      .set(data)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error writing document: ' + error);
        return false;
      });

  });
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: it does not work, when i create a new account.

Comment: it should create an doc thats the userId, a collection called settings, and a doc expiredates with the values above

Comment: This is hard for us to troubleshoot based on just the code, which looks syntactically fine at first glance. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger. Did you check the Cloud Functions console to see if the function is actually invoked? Is there any output? What did it say? Did you try adding debug logging to the function to see which specific statement doesn't do what you expect it to do? Can you reproduce the problem with less code? With fewer products? Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Fiqured it out... It ways a syntax error: it was user.uid instead of userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ways a syntax error: it was user.uid instead of userId